# Support - is this possible with bootstrap?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Hi I'm starting to make some interest in bootstrap. Fast question to see it is worth the time to start :)

Is this - [layout](http://i65.tinypic.com/29eoy2a.png) possible with bootstrap grid system with addition to some CMS (like wordpress, drupal, joomla etc.)? Thanks!

Comment: You should add more details about what you are looking for instead of saying can I use X to be like website Y.

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap uses the [Grid system](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid), so if it fits into a grid, you should be able to do it.

Not all of your website rendered properly, but you should be ok using Bootstrap.

Comment: Ok, thanks for opinion. But I can't imagine how to target content twice - dependent on menu item (once for align left side, once for align right side).

Comment: The website wasn't rendering properly, so I'm not sure how you want to target content based o a menu item. Your question is a little vague and didn't mention this. Bootstrap does a very good job at grid layouts and is responsive by design.

Comment: you Did notice that it was just an image to get a concept, right?Hmmm to be more specific

Comment: REMOWE THE ABOVE --- To be more specific, you insert a 'block' element in html by any modern cms - drupal 8 for example. And you style it by adding classes on different pages etc. So you can target specific pages by css classes and modify the concept. But if I understand correctly you can't target blocks/conteners when using bootstrat grid cause you theme it in html (page). Well there are some ways like tpl.php pages, but this is very time consuming so guess bootstrap won't help me here.

Comment: Here lets grab some links to imagine it better - http://czysto-przyjemnie.pl/o-nas and http://czysto-przyjemnie.pl/cennik for example

Comment: You can style bootstrap however you want, by adding your own CSS. However, think of the grid functionality bootstrap provides as giving you a base layout.